# Event IDs don't match what is displayed in Event Viewer

Tags: windows, winapi, event-log, formatmessage

In the System event log is an event with the following details:

```
Source: Kernel-General
Event ID: 1
Details: The system time has changed to ‎2010‎-‎07‎-‎17T02:58:20.285000000Z from ‎2010‎-‎07‎-‎17T02:58:20.285868600Z.
```

The EVENTLOGRECORD also has a 1 for the EventID field, so it matches what we see in the Event Log viewer.

So far so good.

The problem is, when you look in advapi32.dll which is where this source gets it's messages from, you see this:

```
ID:01000001
String: The system time has changed to %1 from %2.
```

How does the Event Log Viewer magically know to add those extra bits to the ID to find the right string?  Not all event strings have that upper bit, and some have other upper bits set.

Calling FormatMessage with 1 fails.  Calling it with x01000001 succeeds.  But that's not what the event log record contains... :(

No docs that I can find discuss this at all (other that describing the ID format which shows error/severity/facility/code bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you I can't find it documented anywhere, but it looks like Event Viewer maps the `EventType` member of the `EVENTLOGRECORD` structure to the **Severity** bits of the message table identifier.

So for example, Service Control Manager event 7035 is of type "Information", which maps to **Severity** value 1, yielding a message ID of 0x40001B7B, which is indeed the text that Event Viewer displays from netevent.dll: *The %1 service was successfully sent a %2 control.*

Similarly, event 7000 is of type "Error", mapping to **Severity** 3 and a message ID of 0xC0001B58: *The %1 service failed to start due to the following error: %n%2*

Of course that doesn't quite fit with your example; are you sure you've got your 0s and 1s in the right place?

Comment: Hmmm, yes that does work in some circumstances.  Unfortunately, not all as far as I can tell.  Looking in advapi32.dll, there are values where the upper byte is 0D, 76, B5, D4, just to name a few.  That would seem to indicate that the reserved bit is sometimes used, and even facility codes.

Comment: Which platform is that on?  I'm on Windows XP, and the message table entries in advapi32.dll all have either 0x40 or 0x80 as the top byte.

Comment: You make a good point. I'm on Windows 2008 (and I did know that things changed). I've gone through and randomly checked about 50 DLLs in the System32 directory. CertEnroll and AdvApi32 happen to have all sorts of odd numbers, but most of the rest seem to have upper values of 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, B, C. So the Reserved and Customer bits are being used too. Maybe the moral of the story is you really MUST use the new API if looking at Vista/2008 or newer.

Comment: I've contacted Microsoft to see if there is any additional info on predicting event IDs.  I'll report back.

Comment: Reporting back -- no good info from MS -- basically need to use the new Evt APIs. Found this article too:  http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/workshops/InstrWSEight_2.htm#dotnet_event_log_read (section 8.8.1)

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly, in Windows XP and earlier the Event ID was directly mapped to the Message ID within the message table.  With Vista and later there are two ways that the Event ID can be mapped to the Message ID.

1. Event Qualifiers (this is probably what looks like the severity being masked like Brian originally mentioned)
2. Windows Event Template Resource

This article describes the two ways in more detail:
https://github.com/libyal/libevtx/blob/master/documentation/Windows%20XML%20Event%20Log%20(EVTX).asciidoc#message-string-identifier

For this "The system time has changed..." event in particular, Windows 10 is using the Windows Event Template Resource.  If you lookup the EventMessageFile key, in the registry, for this event (based on the Event Source = Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General) you find the Provider DLL.

*Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System\Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General*

You can then use the windows event utility to look at the contents of the provider dll (adding the /gm:true flag will display the message text):

*wevtutil gp Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General /ge:true*

The output shows that Event ID 1 with an Event Task 5 has a Message ID = 16777217 (0x01000001).